# Determine via Apex if product schedules are enabled for an Org

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem

For a given Organization, how can I determine if it has the Product Schedule feature enabled without adding a dependency on that feature to a managed package?

In the UI under **App Setup > Customize > Products > Schedule Setup** it appears as:

[image: Salesforce Product Schedule Enabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this while phrasing the question. Alternatives or improvements are welcome.

From the [Product2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm) documentation:

> Schedules are available only for those organizations that have the
>   products and schedules features enabled. If the organization does not
>   have the schedules feature, the schedule fields do not appear in the
>   DescribeSObjectResult, and you can’t query, create, or update the
>   fields.

So...

```
/**
 * Are product schedules enabled for this Org?
 */
public static boolean schedulesEnabledForOrg() {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeSObjectResult = Product2.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    return describeSObjectResult.fields.getMap().containsKey('CanUseRevenueSchedule');
}
```

This should probably be cached at some level to prevent repeated calls to the metadata for a result that won't change very often.

Comment: It might just be easier to try{ (new Product2()).put('CanUseRevenueSchedule'); }catch(Exception e){ system.debug('nope!'); }

Much faster execution and lower heap space use (although conceptually uglier).

Comment: @ca_peterson Interesting. Coming from a .NET background I've typically thought of exceptions as something to avoid as the alternative would be faster. I guess pulling the meta data can be costly.

Comment: @E.J. Wilburn tested this on a related question. The describe approach was 50% slower: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1056/60