# How to know State and Country Picklist is enabled or not in an org using Apex Class

Tags: apex

How to know State and Country Picklist is enabled in an org or not using Apex Class when working on an app and there may be any org where This picklist is enable or not enable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enabled that feature SFDC create a `countryCode` field for each object where address exists. Then you could check if that field exist using something like this:

```
system.debug(Account.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains('countryCode'));
```

Other generic option:

```
/*
* check if an Sobject has a field
*/
public static boolean hasSObjectField(String fieldName, SObject so){
   String s = JSON.serialize(so);
   // Deserialize it back into a key/value map
   Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);

   // Build a set containing the fields present on our SObject
   Set<String> fieldsPresent = obj.keyset().clone();
   return fieldsPresent.contains(fieldName);
}

Account a = new Account(name='Test');
System.debug(hasSObjectField('BillingCountryCode',a));
```

I posted time ago that function [here](http://devforce.co/apex-tip-check-if-field-exists-on-sobject/)

Comment: Serialize and Deserialize will take some time i guess ?So i still Prefer the one below ..

Comment: You are right about the overtime to serialize/deserialize the SObject, I updated my answer

Comment: I guess event a meta data describe would also take time .Hence Ideal is to catch the exception as below

Comment: I thought that Account metadata description is in cache on execution context. But probably you are right on throw/catch an exception is faster than describe method.

Comment: I agree, the best approach here is to use Account.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap(). Using the serialisation or catching exceptions is more indirect. If you do the check in a static constructor it will only go off once anyway, depending on the overall length of the request the % of time taken for either solution is likely not that significant, though I'd still go via Apex Describe. As it happens this is what I did for this answer as well. https://gist.github.com/afawcett/9345047#file-address-cls-L9

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Thanks! This is what i'm looking for.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett back in the early days of stackexchange EJ Wilburn did some experiments about this type of thing and while I agree the code is less "clean" there are potentially some limits-based advantages to an exception-based approach: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-person-accounts-are-enabled-via-apex-code/1056#1056

Comment: I guess it depends if your doing the check statically (as is the case in the referenced answer in the above comment) or on each call (as is EJ Willburn's proposal). All of these use cases are to check object schema, which is very unlikely to change in the scope of the request. So i am not sure why the results of the check would not be cached statically and thus done once anyway. Hence the use of a static constructor in the above example only consumes one fields describe regardless.

Answer (score 3):

[What's the best way to check if person accounts are enabled via Apex Code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-person-accounts-are-enabled-via-apex-code/1056#1056)

Using the above model for this question as well

```
public Boolean CountryPicklistEnabled(){
try{
    // Try to use the BillingCountryCode field.
    sObject testObject = new Account();
    testObject.get( 'BillingCountryCode' );
    // If we got here without an exception, return true.
    return true;
}
catch( Exception ex ){
    // An exception was generated trying to access the BillingCountryCode field
    return false;
 }
}
```