# Managed Package - check for Person Accounts with post install script

Tags: managed-package, person-accounts

So I was wondering if I can make a managed package with Person Accounts referece and install it on orgs w/ and w/o Persons enabled and then checking in code if it has or hasn't Persons enabled.

Comment: The existing question [What's the best way to check if person accounts are enabled via Apex Code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1055/102) does the great job of covering detecting person accounts. Then you just need to make sure that any references to Person Account specific fields in your managed package code is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks. I read that but I was wondering if a user that installs the managed package with dynamic code based on Person Accounts existing or not, will receive errors.

Comment: The typical approach is to detect if the optional feature is active in the target org, and they only execute the dynamic code if applicable. I.e. detect if Person Accounts are active in the target org and only try and access them if they are. That should avoid any errors around the feature not being available.