# Accounts Missing Organization Feature when install Managed Package with Person Account in organization without Person Account

Tags: managed-package, person-accounts, developer-org

I have Managad Package which uses Person Accounts.

I have next error when I try to install My Managed package  into organization where **Person Account is NOT enabled**.
*(I create it in Dev Organization where Person Account is enabled )*
And I am getting the following error :
[image]
the error text :

> Accounts Missing Organization Feature: Account.RecordType
>
> Missing Organization Feature: B2C

In **all my Apex Code**/methods which has connection to Person Accounst,
**I check if Person Account is enabled** how was mentioned in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-person-accounts-are-enabled-via-apex-code)  (Method 2).

Maybe someone has already done something similar ?

Any help will be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: On the screenshot, it mentions B2C, have you relied on any B2C feature?

Comment: @JefersonChaves I do not use it directly!

Comment: Sure, fair enough but it seems that this is actually what is causing the issue on package deployment. Can you check the feature list on the package upload package?